# Extreme XSLT 1 Flat to Hierarchial Transform needed take 2

Tags: xslt, hierarchical, flat

I am fighting a pretty extreme case of transforming a flat XML into a hierarchical one. I'm also stuck with using XSLT 1.0.  It is acting like it wants to do what I'm trying, but it is not quite there.  You'll likely have to run it to see.  Clearly I need to get my head around how these keys work.  Almost all the examples I find are based upon the value of an attribute... and not a cross-reference between different nodes.

Here is my input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <tns:getDataRS xmlns:tns="http://www.myco.com/DataService">
         <tns:Acknowledgement>Process completed successfully.</tns:Acknowledgement>
         <tns:customer>
            <tns:customerID>210</tns:customerID>
            <tns:visitID>12</tns:visitID>
            <tns:storeID>1</tns:storeID>
            <tns:storeOrder>28</tns:storeOrder>
            <tns:itemID>1</tns:itemID>
            <tns:customerSalesDate>2014-09-26</tns:customerSalesDate>
         </tns:customer>
         <tns:customer>
            <tns:customerID>210</tns:customerID>
            <tns:visitID>12</tns:visitID>
            <tns:storeID>1</tns:storeID>
            <tns:storeOrder>28</tns:storeOrder>
            <tns:itemID>3</tns:itemID>
            <tns:customerSalesDate>2014-09-26</tns:customerSalesDate>
         </tns:customer>
         <tns:customer>
            <tns:customerID>211</tns:customerID>
            <tns:visitID>31</tns:visitID>
            <tns:storeID>2</tns:storeID>
            <tns:storeOrder>48</tns:storeOrder>
            <tns:itemID>2</tns:itemID>
            <tns:customerSalesDate>2014-09-26</tns:customerSalesDate>
         </tns:customer>
         <tns:customer>
            <tns:customerID>211</tns:customerID>
            <tns:visitID>31</tns:visitID>
            <tns:storeID>2</tns:storeID>
            <tns:storeOrder>48</tns:storeOrder>
            <tns:itemID>4</tns:itemID>
            <tns:customerSalesDate>2014-09-26</tns:customerSalesDate>
         </tns:customer>
         <tns:item>
            <tns:customerID>210</tns:customerID>
            <tns:visitID>12</tns:visitID>
            <tns:storeID>1</tns:storeID>
            <tns:itemID>1</tns:itemID>
            <tns:unitPrice>2.95</tns:unitPrice>
            <tns:quantity>4</tns:quantity>
         </tns:item>
         <tns:item>
            <tns:customerID>211</tns:customerID>
            <tns:visitID>31</tns:visitID>
            <tns:storeID>2</tns:storeID>
            <tns:itemID>2</tns:itemID>
            <tns:unitPrice>3.29</tns:unitPrice>
            <tns:quantity>2</tns:quantity>
         </tns:item>
         <tns:item>
            <tns:customerID>210</tns:customerID>
            <tns:visitID>12</tns:visitID>
            <tns:storeID>1</tns:storeID>
            <tns:itemID>3</tns:itemID>
            <tns:unitPrice>4.99</tns:unitPrice>
            <tns:quantity>1</tns:quantity>
         </tns:item>
         <tns:item>
            <tns:customerID>211</tns:customerID>
            <tns:visitID>31</tns:visitID>
            <tns:storeID>2</tns:storeID>
            <tns:itemID>4</tns:itemID>
            <tns:unitPrice>6.95</tns:unitPrice>
            <tns:quantity>2</tns:quantity>
         </tns:item>
      </tns:getDataRS>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tns="http://www.myco.com/DataService">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="storeKey" match="*[local-name() = 'storeID']" use="."/>
    <xsl:key name="orderKey" match="*[local-name() = 'storeOrder']" use="."/>
    <xsl:key name="customerKey" match="*[local-name() = 'customerID']" use="."/>
    <xsl:key name="itemKey" match="*[local-name() = 'itemID']" use="."/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'getDataRS']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <tns:stores>
                <xsl:for-each select="//*[local-name() = 'storeID'][count(. | key('storeKey', .)) > 0]">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tns:stores>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'storeID']">
        <tns:store>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <tns:orders>
                <xsl:for-each select="../*[local-name() = 'storeOrder'][count(. | key('orderKey', .)) > 0]">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tns:orders>
        </tns:store>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'storeOrder']">
        <tns:order><xsl:value-of select="."/></tns:order>
        <tns:salesDate><xsl:value-of select="../*[local-name() = 'customerSalesDate']"/></tns:salesDate>
        <tns:customers>
            <xsl:for-each select="../*[local-name() = 'customerID'][count(. | key('customerKey', .)) > 0]">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tns:customers>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'customerID']">
        <tns:customer>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../*[local-name() = 'visitID']"/>
            <tns:items>
                <xsl:for-each select="../*[local-name() = 'itemID'][count(. | key('itemKey', .)) > 0]">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tns:items>
        </tns:customer>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'itemID']">
        <tns:item>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../*[local-name() = 'unitPrice']"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../*[local-name() = 'quantity']"/>
        </tns:item>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <tns:getDataRS xmlns:tns="http://www.myco.com/DataService">
         <tns:Acknowledgement>Process completed successfully.</tns:Acknowledgement>
         <tns:stores>
            <tns:store>
                <tns:storeID>1</tns:storeID>
                <tns:orders>
                    <tns:order>28</tns:order>
                    <tns:salesDate>2014-09-26</tns:salesDate>
                     <tns:customers>
                        <tns:customer>
                            <tns:customerID>210</tns:customerID>
                            <tns:visitID>12</tns:visitID>
                            <tns:items>
                                <tns:item>
                                    <tns:itemID>1</tns:itemID>
                                    <tns:unitPrice>2.95</tns:unitPrice>
                                    <tns:quantity>4</tns:quantity>
                                </tns:item>
                                <tns:item>
                                    <tns:itemID>3</tns:itemID>
                                    <tns:unitPrice>4.99</tns:unitPrice>
                                    <tns:quantity>1</tns:quantity>
                                </tns:item>
                            </tns:items>
                            </tns:customer>
                     </tns:customers>
                </tns:orders>
            </tns:store>
            <tns:store>
                <tns:storeID>2</tns:storeID>
                <tns:orders>
                    <tns:order>48</tns:order>
                    <tns:salesDate>2014-09-26</tns:salesDate>
                     <tns:customers>
                        <tns:customer>
                            <tns:customerID>211</tns:customerID>
                            <tns:visitID>31</tns:visitID>
                            <tns:items>
                                <tns:item>
                                    <tns:itemID>2</tns:itemID>
                                    <tns:unitPrice>3.29</tns:unitPrice>
                                    <tns:quantity>2</tns:quantity>
                                </tns:item>
                                <tns:item>
                                    <tns:itemID>4</tns:itemID>
                                    <tns:unitPrice>6.95</tns:unitPrice>
                                    <tns:quantity>2</tns:quantity>
                                </tns:item>
                            </tns:items>
                            </tns:customer>
                     </tns:customers>
                </tns:orders>
            </tns:store>
         </tns:stores>
      </tns:getDataRS>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you explain your output relating it with the input?

Comment: Agreed. Given simply an input and an output, there may be multiple sets of rules that produce the same output. We need an actual description of why what you're getting surprises you given what you were trying to do, not just how it differs, or we may give you an answer that works for this case but fails for most others.

Comment: I actually think I have it figured out.  I had written the for-each logic because of an unrelated problem, and have been able to produce the desired result.  For reasons I can't explain, the storeID template needed to key on ALL orders, so a "//*[local-name() = 'storeOrder']..." rather than "../*[local-name() = 'storeOrder']..."